# Serial upvoting reversed issue

Tags: support, reputation

I recently got 1,075 rep and now I only have 637, Reputation log told me that I lost 704 rep on February 17, ironically I didn't earn 704 rep on February 17, What is the problem?

Comment: Just [expand the other dates](http://stackoverflow.com/users/960097/isun?tab=reputation), like February 21st. Seems to work fine to me.

Comment: On February 16, during one five minute span, you received a metric ton of upvotes. This sort of activity can trigger a reversal. You apparently had many such periods of questionable votes applied to your account. It may have been your fault (sockpuppet), or it might have just been you acquired an overzealous fan.

Comment: Probably same person serially upvoted maybe using some accounts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The vote fraud script doesn't work on serial voting patterns immediately. Serial upvoting (and likewise serial downvoting) tends to happen over a period of a couple of days *before* it gets reversed.

There's at least one case of possible serial upvoting on February 16 with a looooooong line of upvotes that all occurred in the span of 5 minutes, accounting for about 200 reputation. I'm not sure where the other 500-ish rep came from, as there doesn't appear to have been any other suspicious voting activity logged in your reputation history since you joined the site. The days on which you went beyond 200 daily reputation had bounty and association bonus activities, so I would rule those out.

Answer (score 14):

The problem seems to be the fact that there are a small number of users that have artificially inflated your reputation.

Looking further into those users that inflated your reputation, it would seem that your account, as well as the accounts of those users, are *very, very* specifically tied to each other, and not tied to *any other accounts* in the same way.

In other words, you have some socks that you were using to artificially inflate your reputation, or you have people you are colluding with in a vote ring.

Comment: Odd how two guys just happen to lavish this guy with votes.  Maybe they want to catch his eye, if you know what I mean?

Comment: I just noticed a large swing in my reputation due to "Serial upvoting reversed". I know that it wasn't me who did it. Is there a way to check who did it (I am just curious who would be voting me up so much)?

Comment: @yakatz I have a good idea who it is and that will be dealt with accordingly.  On a side note, it would appear your co-worker is tossing some votes your way.  Please *do not do this*, voting should be done based on the quality of the post *not the user*.  If we see more of this, we *will* hand out suspensions.

Comment: @casperOne: I was serially upvoted yesterday and of course but natural it was reversed today. I have no issues with that part. My only concern is if the user was trying to be "Thankful" or actually had bad intentions. If it is the 1st then everything is normal but if it is the 2nd then this could pose a problem in the future. Your thoughts please.

Comment: It's not a problem if the user was trying to be "thankful", that's not how voting should work.  If a user upvotes you a bunch of times in a short period of time, they are focusing on the *user*, you.  However, when voting, you should focus on the *post*.  If the user takes the time to review your posts then the serial upvoting script shouldn't kick in.